# How To Verify Access Token on Server

Tags: php, amazon-cognito

So I want to create a game, but I don't want to store user sensitive data on my server (due to new laws ... etc). So I thought cognito might work out well. I read this article of a possible setup https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/gametech/how-to-set-up-player-authentication-with-amazon-cognito/. So I am trying to setup authentification were the client fetches tokens from cognito, and then the server will allow the user call certain functions if it can verify that token.

One thing that confused me is that in the c++ code sample they provided is they verified the client obtained access_token by calling getUserRequest.SetAccessToken(accessToken); to set and ultimately verify the token on the server. Well, in my server I am using php, and I cannot find anything in the sdk to set the access token like this (I looked here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/tree/master/src). However after doing some research on verifying access_tokens from cognito, I found this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html. This article states that access tokens are just JWTs, and you could verify them with a 3rd party JWT library. So I am a little confused... Should I find a function in the aws sdk that verifies the access token on the server, or should I just verify the JWT on its own? In the c++ example, the server also set up a cognito client, is this required to ensure the token is refreshed when it expires?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `getUser` method in the amazon PHP SDK

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html

Example:

```php
$client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient([
    'version' => '2016-04-18',
    'region' => '<aws region>',
]);

try {
    $user = $client->getUser([
        'AccessToken' => '<access_token>',
    ]);
} catch (\Aws\CognitoIdentityProvider\Exception\CognitoIdentityProviderException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still at work, but when I get off work I'll try this out and see if it works, so that I can accept your answer (I am sure it will). Thanks again, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: No worries. Let me know if there is any issues.

Comment: Any suggestions on this will be great. I got the access token using hosted UI. Then I tried to execute this code with that token. I got this exception,      Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata service. (cURL error 7:  (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)) in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo_cognito_client_app\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider.php:240

Comment: @RajeshKumarRaj you need to provide your credentials  in the CognitoIdentityProviderClient:   `'credentials'       => [
'key'       => self::$awsKey,
 'secret'    => self::$awsSecret,
 ]`   key and secret from your amazon user seecurity credentials->create access key